# Can't deploy Rails app to Heroku due to scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

I am having an issue deploying my Ruby project to Heroku. I've searched around but haven't found a solution. My error is this:

```
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...able_background": expected ")", was ": #808080,"
remote:        (in /tmp/build_4a9e512f14d76b318d2a93f5bcb4db07/app/assets/stylesheets/sass/admintable.scss:2)
remote:        /tmp/build_4a9e512f14d76b318d2a93f5bcb4db07/app/assets/stylesheets/sass/admintable.scss:2
```

My scss code it is referring to is this on the second line:

```
$admin_table_colors:(
    admin_table_background: #808080,
    admin_table_header_background: #FF6347,
    admin_table_header_font: orange,
    admin_table_data_background: #808080
);
```

My gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem "pundit"
gem "tzinfo-data"
gem 'lodash-rails'
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "launchy"
  gem "rack_session_access"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "simplecov"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "pry"
  gem "sqlite3"
  gem "guard-rspec", require: false
  gem "thin"
  gem "dotenv-rails"
end

gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.1.1"
gem "faker"
gem "friendly_id"
```

in my environments production file i have this set:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

I do not have .css files only .scss. Should I convert them to css and remove my scss files for the deployment? Maybe my versions of the gems are not proper? Any insights to get that error out of the way would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message tells everything. You have a CSS syntax error on line #2 of `app/assets/stylesheets/sass/admintable.scss`.

Make sure the CSS there is valid. You can probably test locally to validate you've fixed the problem with `rails assets:precompile`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the scss code in my question that was pointed by heroku as the error and there is no error there atleast as scss goes. I should have made that clear. :)

Comment: Post the first few lines of `app/assets/stylesheets/sass/admintable.scss`

Comment: $admin_table_colors:(
    admin_table_background: #808080,
    admin_table_header_background: #FF6347,
    admin_table_header_font: orange,
    admin_table_data_background: #808080
);

Comment: Do you get the same error locally when you `rails assets:precompile`?

Comment: i am a bit of a newb with the whole rails configuration and with that said I tried to run that command in the terminal and I get this error Error: Command 'assets:precompile' not recognized.

Comment: ok so thanks to puneet18 I got to precompile to work and it gave me another error in a scss file.`Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " nav_background": expected ")", was ": #FF6347," (in /assets/stylesheets/sass/dropdown_menu.scss:2)` And the first few lines of my code there is `$navcolors: ( nav_background: #FF6347, nav_font: orange, nav_hover: black, nav_active: orange, search_hover: black, search_active: orange );`

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

## config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

then run command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean

RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

then push all compiles files and menifest file to heroku.

Comment: had a css error in my scss file that doesnt look like it has an error to me as far as scss is concerned. `Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " nav_background": expected ")", was ": #FF6347," (in /assets/stylesheets/sass/dropdown_menu.scss:2)` And the first few lines of my code there is `$navcolors: ( nav_background: #FF6347, nav_font: orange, nav_hover: black, nav_active: orange, search_hover: black, search_active: orange )`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Although I believe my scss code is correct there was a problem in the precompile part. I had to change my map code in all my scss files one example of this is this code:

```
$admin_table_colors:(
    admin_table_background: #808080,
    admin_table_header_background: #FF6347,
    admin_table_header_font: orange,
    admin_table_data_background: #808080
);
```

I had to change it to:

```
$admin_table_colors:(
    'admin_table_background' #808080,
    'admin_table_header_background' #FF6347,
    'admin_table_header_font' orange,
    'admin_table_data_background' #808080
);
```

And then I had to change my map-gets. I had these map gets before:

```
map-get($map: $admin_table_colors, $key: admin_table_background);
```

And then changed it to:

```
map-get($admin_table_colors, 'admin_table_background');
```

I got it to deploy but however my site does not load and I do not know if that has anything to do with that change or it's something else.